# Convert numpy boolean if tuple is a list in a list of tuple

Tags: python, numpy

The objective is to convert list of tuple to `numpy` boolean.

The condition is,
It is `TRUE` is the tuple is a list, and `FALSE` if the tuple is empty

Currently, the list comprehension does the work. But I wonder if there is straight away `numpy` trick to achieve the same result

```
import numpy as np

h=((), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('USER',), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',))

expected_output=np.array([True if len(n) else False for n in h ])
```

Numpy version

```
 "version": "1.21.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is:

```
import numpy as np

h=((), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('USER',), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',), (), ('AUTOREJECT',), ('AUTOREJECT',))

expected_output=np.array(h).astype(bool)
```

Edit: Actually I just noticed a deprecation warning, probably this should be the right way:

```
expected_output=np.array(h, dtype=bool)
```

(Numpy 1.19.5)

Comment: I think you referring to this `VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  expected_output=np.array(h).astype(bool)`

Comment: The alternative suggestion give `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (46,) + inhomogeneous part.`

Comment: Hmm... That's interesting, I could execute that just fine, without any error or warning. What numpy version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the interest in this OP @Szala, the np version is  "version": "1.21.5"

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean now, 1.21.5 gives the same error to me. I guess either use the first option then, or if you want to recreate my case degrade your numpy version, I used "1.19.5"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,appreciate it

Comment: Also be aware of compatibility while changing versions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/toolchain.html
You're welcome!